# MQ automated DLQ handler

Tags: ibm-mq

I am looking to implement an automated DLQ rule file to remove queue full condition in my dev/uat environments. The issue I have is that I want to exclude messages that could be bound for full transmission queues .This is for hopping across multiple queue managers.

I had initially thought the below would work:

```
INPUTQM(qmgrname) WAIT(YES)
REASON(MQRC_Q_FULL) DESTQM(local qmgr name)ACTION(DISCARD) RETRY(5)
```

However on testing, when the transmission queue is full, it does not put the transmission queue header on, the `DESTQM` name does not change to next queue manager intended. The message falls to `DLQ` with remote queue name and 2053 exception, with `DESTQM` still has local `qmgr`.

Wondering if anyone has any ideas on a rule file that could work here?

Answer (score 0):

Filtering by the DESTQ might work, if the names of the queues allow for a pattern or more patterns (then you'd need more rules) that only match the non transmission queues:

> Wildcard characters are supported. You can use the question mark (?)
>   instead of any single character, except a trailing blank; you can use
>   the asterisk (*) instead of zero or more adjacent characters. The
>   asterisk (*) and the question mark (?) are always interpreted as
>   wildcard characters in parameter values.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.adm.doc/q005690_.htm?lang=en